# How to search for an element using an attribute in selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, automation

I am trying to write some code in selenium that will let me select an element by using the value of the attribute "gamename".

When I inspect the code I get this:

```
h4 class= "cardTitle_1ifib5" role="gamename">Test Web </h4>
```

I'm able to select by xpath which is:

```
"//*[@id="root"]/div/main/article/div[1]/div[1]/a/section/div[1]/h4"
```

But I want to be able to search by the value of the game name each time so I can search using data providers.

Just to be clear I want to change the "Test Web" part each time i run the function as thats what will be changing. The selector is as follows:

## root > div > main > article > div.cards_f1mxfh > div:nth-child(2) > a > section > div.cardTop_1ead8bu > h4

I dont know if this helps or not

Comment: </h4> has been removed from the end of the code inspections section, dont know why

Comment: Can you provide the link on which you are testing?

Comment: Have you tried with : String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath")).getText();
   System.out.println(text);

Comment: I can select the link using just the xpath but i want to be able to select the element by inserting the "gamename". so each time i run the the test  i can insert the name as i have a few games and they all have similar xpaths.

Comment: Use Xpath as::"//h4[contains(text(),'Test Web')]"

Comment: Try the above xpath & let me know

Comment: @cruisepandey Seems you have decided to add the `</h4>` to make the HTML a valid one. But OP's comment `</h4> has been removed from the end of the code inspections section, dont know why` clearly indicates there may be some more _child nodes_ or _extra white spaces_ within the `<h4>` node which will clearly conflict with OP's actual issue.

Comment: Its just been removed from stack overflow, not the code. It was just showing me the text when i left it in, not showing any code

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs Can you consider to have a look at the comment I have posted regarding the _Edit_ as proposed by cruisepandey ?

Comment: @fearghalOreilly As I mentioned in my [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524995/how-to-search-for-an-element-using-an-attribute-in-selenium-and-java/50525416#comment88063072_50525416) your actual question was based on a **static node** for which you have recieved **5** well researched answers now changing the same question with your enhanced requirement makes all the answers **invalid** and won't be useful to the future readers and is against all the standards we follow within StackOverflow.com. Please consider to revert back the question to it's original form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find exact text, it seems XPath would be it:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[contains(text(), '" + yourTestLucas + "')]"));
```

By doing this, you can pass the value to it any time by data providers.

As I read your comments, you can make it as a method:

**Case 1**: If you just want to find this element:

```
public WebElement findElementWithRoleName(String yourTestLucas) {
    return webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[contains(text(), '" + yourTestLucas + "')]"));
}
```

**Case 2**: If you want to click on this element:

```
public void clickElementWithRoleName(String yourTestLucas) {
    webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[contains(text(), '"+ yourTestLucas + "')]")).click();
}
```

Comment: And if i want to click this element how do i do that with a void, apologies im quite new to automation testing

Comment: @fearghalOreilly I updated my answer, hope it gives you some idea :)

Comment: Thanks that great, although i just realised ive not explained it great, the role name isnt changing, its the value of the role, so basically "Test Lucas" is what i want to change each test not the gamename                <h4 class="cardTitle_1ifib5" role="gamename">Test Lucas</h4>

Comment: Still not working :))) this is the css if it helps in any way #root > div > main > article > div.cards_f1mxfh > div:nth-child(2) > a > section > div.cardTop_1ead8bu > h4

Comment: Usually this stuff works no prob, its just not selecting it for some reason

Comment: Not working means it throws Exception or it does nothing? I am not sure about setAttribute, because you want to find element `h4` with `text=Test Lucas` to click on it, so setAttribute is not really for this case. Can you give more info about not working?

Comment: The test isnt finding the element and its just failing org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element. Very annoying. Usually its not very hard to select the element, its not even picking it up using a standard xpath which is usually a last resort

Comment: Sadly its all been in vain org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified.

Comment: I personally don't like xPath, I prefer cssSelector, but in this case, it seems xPath would do it. I updated my answer. Let's try xPath to see if it still fails ;)

Comment: Cheers, it's great to hear !!!, also feel free to accept this answer if it helped you, in order to help others in future :)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has an option through which you get retrieve attributes of elements.
`[yourXpath].getAttribute("name");`

Comment: Hi, yes i know how to do that but how would i be able to just enter the "name" attribute as a variable string each time i run the code so it will find the element using the string?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, for that attribute you will have a dinamic string to search? It may change from an execution to another?

Comment: Yea thats correct, im basically testing a page that has different game cards on the page, its a "game lobby" but each game has a different name so i want to be able to search by name, theyre in no particular order so an xpath doesnt work, neither does a css selector

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. In this case, the first solution that came into my mind is that maybe you could fetch all the info in the game lobby, store it in an array, and then through `regex matcher` search, match the info you're interested in. This can be done using `matcher` and `pattern`. I'm not sure this would work in your case, but you may give it a try if you want

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared and your code trials to identify the element through the `value` attribute you can use the following *Locator Strategy*:

- *xpath*:

  ```
  "//h4[starts-with(@class,'cardTitle_1ifib') and @role='gamename'][normalize-space()='Test Web']"
  ```

Comment: **No**, you shouldn't. As per this question my solution is based on the static string **gamename**. If you want to pass a variable `String` through a `function()` call, you possibly need to raise a new question with your new requirement as you can't change the question now due to arrival of several well researched answers based on your current question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood question correctly, here are few examples how to achive attribute element handling:

**1. via css selector:**

```
webDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h4[role ='gamename']");
```

**2. via xPath:**

```
webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//h4[@role='gamename']"))
```

or

```
webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role='gamename']"))
```

**3. via WebElement method:**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(...);
element.getAttribute("role")
```

Some of this example should work.

Hope this helps.